# how do i use ahk app to create right click menu option

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script in msword which can print the current page when clicked on button created in toolbar, and also a keyboard shortcut ctrl+o to print.
The ahk script code which contains ctrl+0 shortcut works just fine. But I have to open manually word documents each time to do that, and I have hundreds documents to print every day.

I wanted to add a script or keyboard shortcut using ahk in right click context menu in windows, so that when I right click on my word files in folder it can do the same without opening the word files.

I tried adding the ahk script in regedit...HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers. But it gives me an error : `This app can't run on your pc.`
Any idea how can i do that ?

Comment: How do you run the AHK script in the registry? You likely have to compile the `.ahk` to an `.exe` in order for it to work.